# Insignificant Coefficient and sign interpretation

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

If a coefficient is negative but insignificant on 10% while the 95% confidence interval contains both positive and negative values, what can you actually say about the sign?

Ex: Coefficient B = -0.5, p-value = 0.3, 95% conf-interval = [-1.5,1]

There are no biases in the model.

Comment: You need to give us more details about the model and the exact null hypothesis that your p-value is supposed to test, and the exact way the confidence intervals are estimated. Normally (the null-hypothesis is that the coefficient is 0, and the confidence interval is directly related to the test) this cannot happen. It may happen if the p-value test a different null hypothesis or if the confidence interval is some sort of approximation (e.g. delta method).

Comment: The p-value is to test if the coefficient is 0 using an F-test i.e. F = (B/(SE(B))^2. while the confidence interval is 95% confidence interval in which the coefficient is. i.e. B+sqrt(F(1,degrees of freedom))*SE(B) and B-sqrt(F(1,degrees of freedom))*SE(B).

SE = standard error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot conclude anything about the sign of the coefficient. Since the 95% confidence interval for the coefficient spans (-1.5,1), we are 95% confident that B is some value between -1.5 and 1. We cannot distinguish the coefficient statistically from 0. We also cannot conclude that $B$ is less than 0 (or, equivalently, that $B$ is negative). The short version is that if you cannot conclude $B$ is different from 0, you cannot conclude that $B$ is less than (or greater than) 0 given the same data.

A lengthier explanation to that last sentence: In order to test $H_0: B<0$ against the alternative $H_A: B \geq 0$, you would take $\alpha=0.1$ and halve it to be $\alpha^*=0.05$. Since $p=0.3>0.05=\alpha^*$, you cannot conclude that $B$ is less than 0. The same process holds for $B$ greater than 0.

Comment: I can rephrase to say "$B$ is some value between," but do you think it is otherwise incorrect?

Comment: Depends on your definition of the word "confident". Yes, it's wrong to say that there's a 95% chance of the true parameter being inside the interval, but that's not necessarily what "confident" means. I think calling that "blatantly wrong" is being pretty pedantic.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect but your last sentence is.  Confidence is not equivalent to probability, nor is that the implication in my post. All due respect, but my post isn't "blatantly wrong."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the alpha is on a 10% level for the null hypothesis  ?

Comment: This answer should not be accepted — it is fundamentally not how hypothesis testing works. The null hypothesis is the default hypothesis — it is never 'concluded' — and a higher calculated p-value than the threshold (here, .05) means you fail to reject the null hypothesis (which in this example, is also written incorrectly). We never 'conclude' a hypothesis is correct: we deduce that the opposite is very unlikely. To deduce that a coefficient is likely negative, we need to find it very statistically unlikely that the coefficient is greater than or equal to 0.